# Wired network computer taking down whole network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, internet

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 machine wired to the same network as 20 other Ethernet connected Windows PCs.

The Ubuntu machine doesn't share any folders - it just uses the internet.

Every so often the Ubuntu computer screen will go into power save mode, and the mouse and keyboard don't work to wake the computer. A restart is required to resume normal function.

While the computer can't be woken from this state, the entire internet network is down. Is there a log to check what was happening? How can I fix this for the future?

I checked `/var/log/syslog` and there's probably a thousand repeated errors over the day `Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region, inode 19663270` but I'm unsure if it's related.

```
$ find /home/user/ -inum 19663270
/home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/blqjbhef.default/safebrowsing/google4/goog-malware-proto.pset
```

Comment: How is the network set up on the machine? Hardcoded IP or does it use DHCP? What is the address of the gateway for other machines? You can use the `arp` command to relate IP address and machines.